# statistics analysis to find dependence between two variables

Tags: correlation, descriptive-statistics

I have a question I appreciate that if somebody can help me. I am working on hydrological model in agriculture area. At this moment I want to figure out if farmers consider the soil characteristics in their irrigation planning or not. I have soil types of some of this farms as well as irrigation timing for these farms.
what is the best statistics test to see if there is any relation between soil type and irrigation?

Comment: What exactly is the outcome variable here? Whether they irrigate at all, the lag time between irrigations, the amount of water used in an irrigation?

Comment: I have both lag time between irrigations and amount of water used.

Comment: are there any covariates you need to consider (crop type, season, water prices?)

Comment: At the first step I don't want to consider these covariates.